# Getting server response data with angularjs blueimp fileupload?

Tags: angularjs, upload, blueimp

I am trying to get the blueimp file upload plugin to play nicely with my app, using angularjs. I am having one issue. My server returns json data upon a successful upload. The problem is I cannot retrieve this data, although I can find it in the console.

```
$scope.$on('fileuploadprocessdone', function(event, files){
                console.log(files);
            });
```

Console:

```
Object {disabled: false, create: null, dropZone: x.fn.x.init[1], pasteZone: x.fn.x.init[1], replaceFileInput: true…}
_progress: Object
_response: Object
    jqXHR: Object
    result: Object
    textStatus: "success"
```

I am trying to get the "result" Object in the "_response" object:

```
$scope.$on('fileuploadprocessdone', function(event, files){
                console.log(files._response);
                console.log(files.response);
            });
```

returns (console) :

```
Object {} //first console log
function () {
            return this._response;  //second console log
        }
```

I can clearly see the data returned by the server in the first console.log(files). How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can now prevent default event actions in Angular scope listeners, too:

```
   $scope.$on('fileuploaddone', function(e, data){
      console.log(data.result);
   });
```